# Getting false when tried to encode json php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I was tring to get values from mysql db and creating json from php. But am always getting "false" as reply.

My query is working correctly .

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";
$charset="UTF8";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sth = mysqli_query("select
    a.id,
    a.fname,
a.mname,a.lname,a.country,a.city,a.dob,a.role,
    a.email,
    b.mobile,b.skypeid,b.address,b.languages,
c.height,
c.width,
c.skin,
c.bust,
c.waist,
c.hips,
c.shoesize,
c.hair,
c.eye,
c.comments,
d.movie,
d.advertisement,
d.brandpromotional,
d.danceshow,
d.runway,
d.catalog,
d.editorial,
d.fit,
d.casual,
d.corporate,
d.swimwear,
d.fitness,
d.magazine,
d.lingerie,
d.glamour,
d.alternative,
d.hair,
d.legs,
d.hands,
d.webmodel,
d.social,
d.experience

from
    basicinfo a
        join contactdetails b
            on a.email=b.email
         join measurements c
             on a.email = c.email
         join areainterest d
on a.email=d.email
where a.role='Model'");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

please help me

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($rows)` right before your json_encode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_encode() returns false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440529/json-encode-returns-false)

Comment: am getting this one array(0) { }

Comment: its not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440529/json-encode-returns-false..please read both questions

Comment: @Bangalore aside from the specifics of the application, it's the same problem and it's almost guaranteed to have both the same cause and solution. See the accepted answer on that question for a way you can help to debug your problem.

Comment: Doesn't the query need to be executed? I'm not that familiar with mysqli, but I know the old mysql required an execute command. This seems to set the query and examine the result without executing it.

Answer (score 1):

this one is working..

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";
$charset="UTF8";

// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
} 

$sth = "select
    a.id,
    a.fname,
a.mname,a.lname,a.country,a.city,a.dob,a.role,
    a.email,
    b.mobile,b.skypeid,b.address,b.languages,
c.height,
c.width,
c.skin,
c.bust,
c.waist,
c.hips,
c.shoesize,
c.hair,
c.eye,
c.comments,
d.movie,
d.advertisement,
d.brandpromotional,
d.danceshow,
d.runway,
d.catalog,
d.editorial,
d.fit,
d.casual,
d.corporate,
d.swimwear,
d.fitness,
d.magazine,
d.lingerie,
d.glamour,
d.alternative,
d.hair,
d.legs,
d.hands,
d.webmodel,
d.social,
d.experience

from
    basicinfo a
        join contactdetails b
            on a.email=b.email
         join measurements c
             on a.email = c.email
         join areainterest d
on a.email=d.email
where a.role='Model'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sth) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query is missing the connection parameter but since you are `new mysqli` and not `mysqli_connect` it looks like you need to query the data in a different way... the easiest way to update your code would be to do this:

Change this:

```
$sth = mysqli_query("select
```

To this:

```
$sth = $conn->query("select
```

Then change this:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
```

To this:

```
while($r = $sth->fetch_assoc()) {
```

PHP has three different ways you can connect to the database: object oriented style, procedural style or using PDO.  The code was intermixing the object oriented and procedural style so it wasn't working as expected. mysqli_query was also missing the link variable which is the first parameter.

Read more here: http://php.net/mysqli_query